# Can charts in png format be styled in CF 2016?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

**Update**: found that using style attribute to point to a json file in charting folder allows me to set styles and use png successfully

I am running into a problem and not sure if I'm overlooking a limitation or if something else is going on. We are migrating from CF10 to CF2016 and resolving some differences with charting. I see JSON styling that can be applied and would probably meet our needs. However, an error is being generated when we set the format to be png which we need.

Here is the exact code from the legend styling section of the [cfchart documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfchart.html) with the only difference being the change from html to png.

```
  <cfscript>
         legend={"background-color":"lightgray"};
  </cfscript>
  <cfchart format="png" title="Graph" chartHeight="400" chartWidth="600" showLegend="yes" legend="#legend#">
         <cfchartseries type="line" serieslabel="WBC" markerstyle="circle" color="red">
               <cfchartdata item="Day 1" value="19.2"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 2" value="15.2"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 3" value="15.1"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 4" value="12.6"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 5" value="14.2"/>
         </cfchartseries>
         <cfchartseries type="line" serieslabel="HCT" markerstyle="diamond" color="blue" >
               <cfchartdata item="Day 1" value="39.2"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 2" value="35.2"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 3" value="35.1"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 4" value="32.6"/>
               <cfchartdata item="Day 5" value="34.2"/>
         </cfchartseries>
  </cfchart>
```

Simply flipping the format to png causes the following error. (just throw into trycf.com with CF2016 engine selected to see full error)

```
Cause:  
    [struct]
    Message: For input string: "NaN"
    StackTrace: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at com.zingchart.Utils.parseColor(Utils.java:31)
        at com.zingchart.Context2d.jsSet_fillStyle(Context2d.java:159)
        (clipped)
    Suppressed:  
        [array]
    TagContext:  
        [array]
        1) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CF_OPTRUNTIME
            LINE: 1
            RAW_TRACE: at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c9._c0(:1)
            TEMPLATE: 
            TYPE: CFML 
        2) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CFCHART
            LINE: 18
            RAW_TRACE: at cfmain15096445073382d5ed396b32dbea22da2472da7a72d2f4286abb0062ecfm2dEBEF295F2dD9242d08502d97FAE6A3861669DA2ecfm439568922.runPage(EBEF3FC8-F3B7-F956-B1B68C22EC270E13-EBEF295F-D924-0850-97FAE6A3861669DA.cfm:18)
            TEMPLATE: EBEF3FC8-F3B7-F956-B1B68C22EC270E13-EBEF295F-D924-0850-97FAE6A3861669DA.cfm
            TYPE: CFML 
        3) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CFINCLUDE
            LINE: 168
            RAW_TRACE: at cfcfmler2ecfc1489966816$func$RUNIT.runFunction(/home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc:168)
            TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc
            TYPE: CFML 
        4) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CF_UDFMETHOD
            LINE: 79
            RAW_TRACE: at cfcfmler2ecfc1489966816$funcPLAYCFMFILE.runFunction(/home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc:79)
            TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc
            TYPE: CFML 
        5) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CF_TEMPLATEPROXY
            LINE: 81
            RAW_TRACE: at cfgetremote2ecfm1955103781.runPage(/home/webs/sbx/www/getremote.cfm:81)
            TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/getremote.cfm
            TYPE: CFML 
    Type: java.lang.NumberFormatException

ColumnNumber: 0
LineNumber: 1
Message: Wrapped java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN" (#1)
ScriptStackTrace: [empty string]
SourceName: 
StackTrace: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN" (#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1773)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:183)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:319)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:1729)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1557)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1547)
    at com.zingchart.zingchart_rhino_min._c_anonymous_250(Unknown Source)
    at com.zingchart.zingchart_rhino_min.call(Unknown Source)
    (clipped)
Suppressed:  
    [array]
TagContext:  
    [array]
    1) [struct]
        COLUMN: 0
        ID: CF_OPTRUNTIME
        LINE: 1
        RAW_TRACE: at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c9._c0(:1)
        TEMPLATE: 
        TYPE: CFML 
    2) [struct]
        COLUMN: 0
        ID: CFCHART
        LINE: 18
        RAW_TRACE: at cfmain15096445073382d5ed396b32dbea22da2472da7a72d2f4286abb0062ecfm2dEBEF295F2dD9242d08502d97FAE6A3861669DA2ecfm439568922.runPage(EBEF3FC8-F3B7-F956-B1B68C22EC270E13-EBEF295F-D924-0850-97FAE6A3861669DA.cfm:18)
        TEMPLATE: EBEF3FC8-F3B7-F956-B1B68C22EC270E13-EBEF295F-D924-0850-97FAE6A3861669DA.cfm
        TYPE: CFML 
    3) [struct]
        COLUMN: 0
        ID: CFINCLUDE
        LINE: 168
        RAW_TRACE: at cfcfmler2ecfc1489966816$func$RUNIT.runFunction(/home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc:168)
        TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc
        TYPE: CFML 
    4) [struct]
        COLUMN: 0
        ID: CF_UDFMETHOD
        LINE: 79
        RAW_TRACE: at cfcfmler2ecfc1489966816$funcPLAYCFMFILE.runFunction(/home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc:79)
        TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc
        TYPE: CFML 
    5) [struct]
        COLUMN: 0
        ID: CF_TEMPLATEPROXY
        LINE: 81
        RAW_TRACE: at cfgetremote2ecfm1955103781.runPage(/home/webs/sbx/www/getremote.cfm:81)
        TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/getremote.cfm
        TYPE: CFML 
Type: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException
WrappedException:  
    [struct]
    Message: For input string: "NaN"
    StackTrace: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at com.zingchart.Utils.parseColor(Utils.java:31)
        at com.zingchart.Context2d.jsSet_fillStyle(Context2d.java:159)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor149.invoke(Unknown Source)
        (clipped)
    Suppressed:  
        [array]
    TagContext:  
        [array]
        1) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CF_OPTRUNTIME
            LINE: 1
            RAW_TRACE: at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c9._c0(:1)
            TEMPLATE: 
            TYPE: CFML 
        2) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CFCHART
            LINE: 18
            RAW_TRACE: at cfmain15096445073382d5ed396b32dbea22da2472da7a72d2f4286abb0062ecfm2dEBEF295F2dD9242d08502d97FAE6A3861669DA2ecfm439568922.runPage(EBEF3FC8-F3B7-F956-B1B68C22EC270E13-EBEF295F-D924-0850-97FAE6A3861669DA.cfm:18)
            TEMPLATE: EBEF3FC8-F3B7-F956-B1B68C22EC270E13-EBEF295F-D924-0850-97FAE6A3861669DA.cfm
            TYPE: CFML 
        3) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CFINCLUDE
            LINE: 168
            RAW_TRACE: at cfcfmler2ecfc1489966816$func$RUNIT.runFunction(/home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc:168)
            TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc
            TYPE: CFML 
        4) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CF_UDFMETHOD
            LINE: 79
            RAW_TRACE: at cfcfmler2ecfc1489966816$funcPLAYCFMFILE.runFunction(/home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc:79)
            TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/cfmler.cfc
            TYPE: CFML 
        5) [struct]
            COLUMN: 0
            ID: CF_TEMPLATEPROXY
            LINE: 81
            RAW_TRACE: at cfgetremote2ecfm1955103781.runPage(/home/webs/sbx/www/getremote.cfm:81)
            TEMPLATE: /home/webs/sbx/www/getremote.cfm
            TYPE: CFML 
    Type: java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Am I overlooking a limitation in cfchart in CF 2016, or this simply a bug I need to report? I have the latest update. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you found a solution to your question please post it as an answer, not an update to the question. Then accept that answer as the solution.  That way others will find it that come across this post.

Comment: @Miguel-F yep, well aware. I posted a work around but want to get others' feedback if possible. See Scott's answer for example. Will give this some time

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is from the CF Documentation, but as you've shown, it fails when switching to PNG format.

The error message is the clue; Message: For input string: "NaN".

Apparently, when you use the PNG format, it can't figure out how to use the CSS stylesheet color names and requires the color code.

For example, this will work and set the background color to red for the legend.

```
<cfscript>
    legend={"background-color":"ff0000"};
</cfscript>
```